# d3 table dynamic column left border line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

Trying to manipulate d3 table.  So following line works:

```
// this code works
tbody.selectAll('td:nth-child(4)')
.style('border-left', '1px solid #000000');
```

but I wanted to dynamically choose the nth-child index which is stored in an array.

```
//does not work
tbody.data([3,5,8,11])
.enter()
.selectAll('td:nth-child(' + function(d) { return d + ')'; })
.style('border-left', '1px solid #000000');
```

I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: tbody.data(...).enter(...).selectAll is not a function

What am I doing wrong?  Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely wrong, but it seems to me that you don't want to bind any data to your DOM elements: that `[3,5,8,11]` array is just the numbers of the children you want to manipulate.

Loops are rather frowned upon in a D3 code (meaning that almost always the loop is unnecessary). However, if my assumption above is correct, this is an adequate situation for using a loop:

```
[3,5,8,11].forEach(function(d){
    selection.selectAll('td:nth-child(' + d + ')')
        .style('border-left', '1px solid #000000');
});
```

Where `selection` is your D3 selection for the table.

Alternatively, in a more idiomatic solution, you could just use the second argument (which is the index) in your `td` selection, that way avoiding the infamous loop. Something like this:

```
.style('border-left', function(d,i){
    if([3,5,8,11].indexOf(i) > -1){
        return '1px solid #000000'
    }
})
```